# Content Porter SP1 throwing Error while importing content

Tags: tridion

Hello Tridion Experts,

I am running into a number of issues while Importing content using Content Porter SP1.

1. Fail to import all the Categories with all Keywords
2. Fail to import Components which are copied
3. Fail to import Structure Groups

here are the error details

```
8/8/2012 10:13:25 PM    [Information]   Resolving item mappings
8/8/2012 10:13:25 PM    [Information]   Mappings resolving started
8/8/2012 10:13:25 PM    [Information]   Mappings resolving finished
8/8/2012 10:13:25 PM    [Information]   Discovering potential problems
8/8/2012 10:13:25 PM    [Information]   Problems discovery started
8/8/2012 10:13:26 PM    [Information]   Problems discovery finished
8/8/2012 10:13:26 PM    [Information]   Import started
8/8/2012 10:13:26 PM    [Information]   Importing System Administration items
8/8/2012 10:13:26 PM    [Information]   Importing items into '040 XXX XXXXX Website' Publication
8/8/2012 10:13:26 PM    [Information]   Importing items into '040 XXX XXXXX Website' Publication started at 18:13:26
8/8/2012 10:13:27 PM    [Error] <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040200" Category="4" Source="Kernel" Severity="2" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040200" Cause="false" MessageID="16137"><![CDATA[Unable to save Publication (tcm:0-0-0).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_4452</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:0-0-0</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040200" Cause="true" MessageID="15748"><![CDATA[Unable to map all paths to URIs.]]></tcm:Line><tcm:Details><tcm:CallStack><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Create(UserContext,String)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Publication.Save</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Request.SaveItem</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Request</tcm:Location></tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details></tcm:Error>

8/8/2012 10:13:27 PM    [Information]   Import failed
=======
Start time: 2012-08-08 18:13:26
End time: 2012-08-08 18:13:27

All changes made during import process were rolled back
8/8/2012 10:13:27 PM    [Error] Transactional import failed. No changes will be commited.
8/8/2012 10:13:27 PM    [Information]   Import completed
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the publication '040 Merck Connect Website' exist in the Tridion instance you are importing to?

Answer (score 4):

You mention you are running into a number of issues but the error message you provide actually seems to report only a single failure (which would prevent all further actions to take place indeed).

The error you get is `Unable to save Publication` with the standard WebDAV explanation of `Unable to map all paths to URIs.`.

So the comment Quirijn made about whether the **040 XXX XXXXX Website** Publication actually exists seems indeed relevant. However it shouldn't matter if it does or does not exist as long as the user who is importing this has enough rights in the system to create items (specifically Publications).

So I would check the following:

1. Are you importing through the Content Porter with a Tridion Administrator account?
2. When you log into the UI, are you able to Create the Publication **040 XXX XXXXX Website** manually?
3. If you are able to complete #2, does the import work after that?

If you can import after #2, then my guess is that you didn't export the Publication itself in Content Porter, but my first thoughts would be that you are trying to import with a user with insufficient rights to create the Publication or any items inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for Answer, But somehow that was not an issue. 
Resolution was that I have failed to installed root publication 100%. That is why I was facing issue with Category& keywords.
And yeah there is no need to do anything manually while we are importing... that will break the blueprint somehow.

to solved this issue I need to clear all publication and need to Import root publication with 100% tridion artifact should be cover.

Thanks,
Hiren

Answer (score 2):

I know that you have resolved this question, but I came across the same error and wanted to provide a little bit more information based on how I solved it. In my case I was importing a publication that inherited from a publication I had previously imported with Content Porter. As you mentioned in your solution Hiren, my issue was in the previous publication, specifically the lack of a "root" structure group in the publication to be inherited. Since publications cannot be inherited without a root structure group this was preventing the creation of my new publication during the import. Once I created a root structure group in my parent publication the import went off without a hitch.